# Is there a faster way to find matching features in two arrays (Python)?

Tags: python, optimization, comparison, bioinformatics

I'm trying to go through each feature in one file (1 per line) and find all matching features based on one column of that line in a second file. I have this solution, which does what I want on small files, but it's very slow on big files (my files have >20,000,000 lines). [Here's a sample of the two input files.](https://gist.github.com/ethanagbaker/dc7bc62a413cbbc32bbf944125845afd)

My (slow) code:

```
FEATUREFILE = 'S2_STARRseq_rep1_vsControl_peaks.bed'
CONSERVATIONFILEDIR = './conservation/'
with open(str(FEATUREFILE),'r') as peakFile, open('featureConservation.td',"w+") as outfile:
for line in peakFile.readlines():
    chrom = line.split('\t')[0]
    startPos = int(line.split('\t')[1])
    endPos = int(line.split('\t')[2])
    peakName = line.split('\t')[3]
    enrichVal = float(line.split('\t')[4])

    #Reject negative peak starts, if they exist (sometimes this can happen w/ MACS)
    if startPos > 0:
        with open(str(CONSERVATIONFILEDIR) + str(chrom)+'.bed','r') as conservationFile:
            cumulConserv = 0.
            n = 0
            for conservLine in conservationFile.readlines():
                position = int(conservLine.split('\t')[1])
                conservScore = float(conservLine.split('\t')[3])
                if position >= startPos and position <= endPos:
                    cumulConserv += conservScore
                    n+=1
        featureConservation = cumulConserv/(n)
        outfile.write(str(chrom) + '\t' + str(startPos) + '\t' + str(endPos) + '\t' + str(peakName) + '\t' + str(enrichVal) + '\t' + str(featureConservation) + '\n')
```

Comment: have you considered sorting `conservationFile` by the position, this way you can reduce the complexity of this to N rather N^2 assuming the `peakFile` is sorted as well. (you can use `sort -r -k2` for that)

Comment: Use Pandas.  It might change your life.

Comment: @Chris OP wasn't looking for a library recommendation.

Comment: `for line in peakFile.readlines():` will read the whole file into memory at once. `for line in peakFile:` will read one line at a time.

Comment: @Chris I'm familiar w/ Pandas, but didn't think parsing these files into data tables would speed it up. Also there's an issue with needing to open a particular file based on information in the first file.

Comment: `line.split('\t')` produces the same result every time you call it, so why not cache it?

Comment: @Ethan It will speed it up immensely.  Pandas was literally created for this type of thing.  You can obviously do it in standard python, but even with tweaks here and there it's not suitable for massive data sets.

Comment: You need both files to be sorted then finding overlaps in easy as long as you do not load entire file in memory. You could code this in python, but why? Existing tools.will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for my purposes seems to be rewriting the above code for pandas. Here's what's working well for me on some very large files:

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd

FEATUREFILE = 'S2_STARRseq_rep1_vsControl_peaks.bed'
CONSERVATIONFILEDIR = './conservation/'

peakDF = pd.read_csv(str(FEATUREFILE), sep = '\t', header=None, names=['chrom','start','end','name','enrichmentVal'])
#Reject negative peak starts, if they exist (sometimes this can happen w/ MACS)
peakDF.drop(peakDF[peakDF.start <= 0].index, inplace=True)
peakDF.reset_index(inplace=True)
peakDF.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
peakDF['conservation'] = 1.0 #placeholder

chromNames = peakDF.chrom.unique()

for chromosome in chromNames: 
    chromSubset = peakDF[peakDF.chrom == str(chromosome)]
    chromDF = pd.read_csv(str(CONSERVATIONFILEDIR) + str(chromosome)+'.bed', sep='\t', header=None, names=['chrom','start','end','conserveScore'])

for i in xrange(0,len(chromSubset.index)):
    x = chromDF[chromDF.start >= chromSubset['start'][chromSubset.index[i]]]
    featureSubset = x[x.start < chromSubset['end'][chromSubset.index[i]]]
    x=None
    featureConservation = float(sum(featureSubset.conserveScore)/(chromSubset['end'][chromSubset.index[i]]-chromSubset['start'][chromSubset.index[i]]))
    peakDF.set_value(chromSubset.index[i],'conservation',featureConservation)
    featureSubset=None

 peakDF.to_csv("featureConservation.td", sep = '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with you are looping over ALL of `conservationFile` every time you read a single line from `peakFile` so stick a `break` after `n+=1` in the if statement and that should help somewhat. Assuming that there is only one match that is.

Another option is to try using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) which may help with buffering

Comment: Ah, there's more than one match. The peakFile has information on a range of positions that constitute that feature (ie peak 1 is position 1-200). conservationFile has a score for each individual position, so I need to find all of those conservationFile entries that are within the range of the peakFile feature.

Comment: Ok, my bad. but like @Chris said seriously check out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) it might change you life

Answer (score 0):

Bedtools was made for this, specifically the `intersect` function:

http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html

Comment: I was having problems preserving some of the extra data in additional columns when I tried bedtools.

Comment: You can merge them with a delimiter, such as underscore (`_`) then split them after e.g. `perl -p -e "s/_/\t/g;"`. I acknowledge that bedtools is somewhat ill-suited for non-BED data, but  the benefits out weigh the drawbacks as it is highly optmizied for performance and has a plethora of command and options.  You can also split out the extra cols and add them back later with `awk` or `paste` depending on the output you obtain. I am happy to help out on this.